# How to Fix Unwanted Space in a Responsive React App Using Tailwind and Framer Motion?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, framer-motion

I'm currently stuck in my portfolio project.

First, this is the repo url : https://github.com/SAntoineS/react_portfolio

I can't upload videos but there is two state of the visual effect, this weird visual it's only when my app is responsive on the phone.

I'm using Tailwind for CSS and responsive and Framer Motion for animation.

First :
[image: First Image]

I don't know why there is a space after my app at right

But when I start scrolling, after 2sec there's no more space and all the layout is good.

Second :
[image: Second Image]

I checked in responsive phone view there's nothing that extends beyond the edge.
I searched in my app but can't find where's the problem...

If you can help me, you can test this by clone this project.
If you want specific file just ask me.

Thanks.